# Is it possible for a Kafka Connect connector to be configured to skip rows with specific values?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a sink connector that writes rows to a MySQL database. I'd like to skip rows which have a "source": "whatever" key: value pair. Is this possible?

Comment: You have to write your own Single Message Transform (SMT) in order to achieve this.

Comment: I figured that might be the case but wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way to do this. Thanks

Comment: But also, how do you get an SMT to simply not write to a database?

Comment: @Hassan, It has to return `null` for particular message and message won't be passed to `SinkTask`. It is generic behaviour of Kafka Connect - apply to all types of Connectors

Comment: @wardziniak Makes sense, thanks